# Integration testing for Javascript Code

Tags: javascript, web-services, integration-testing

I've written a lot of javascript code that interacts with a number of different web services. I now need to write integration testing code for it. My experience with integration testing is limited. Could anyone recommend some good tools and online tutorials?

Answer (score 0):

look at this post this may help you i guess... http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/4026880618/javascript-integration-testing-example-installing-and

Answer (score 0):

We use cucumber http://cukes.info/ so we create functional testing that tests integration with server too.
cucumber runs with ruby, if you want to do it with JS try cucumberjs or a combination of zombiejs and jasminejs. NodeJS required